# Are there items similar to the Pythagorean cup?

Tags: teaching

I believe it's a great application of Pascal's Law. Are there ways to overcome it? I mean, not having the fluid drop through the tube. One way I Know is to put a denser fluid in first and on top of it a comparatively less dense one.

***Answer if you want to***: Also are there other toys which can aid a 5-7 year old learn concepts of science and also the equipment required should be very minimal.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection to history here. It seems to be a question about a physical principle.

Comment: This is a good question but it does not fit to the scope of this site, according to the help center.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Would you suggest the Physics page? Or if possible can help me 'migrate' this question from here to the Physics site?

Comment: @Wave Metric: you may try of course. There is no "science education SE" as far as I know.

Comment: [Now on Physics.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225149/are-there-items-similar-to-the-pythagorean-cup) Therefore, I'm closing the HSM version of this question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko There is a proposal on Area 51 that has been around for just about a month:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92559/science-educators